# hexadecimal to nsuinteger cocoa

Tags: cocoa

How can i convert a Hexadecimal number to a nsuinteger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NSScanner` if your hex number is in an `NSString`:

```
NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"0xFF"];
unsigned int foo;
[scanner scanHexInt:&foo];
NSLog(@"Integer: %ld",foo);
scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"FF"];
[scanner scanHexInt:&foo];
NSLog(@"Integer: %ld",foo);
```

Admittedly, this doesn't scan directly to an NSUInteger, you'd need to cast the result, but it should be enough for your purposes.

Comment: If I answered your question, you should mark the question as answered, this way more people will help you in future.

Comment: Sorry, i am new to this blog. But, will make it out in the future. Any way, thanx for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
strtoul(s, NULL, 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one [solution](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2003/Jan/msg00325.html) which uses the `libc` function `sscanf()`,